# Air NZ Status Tier renewal (downgrade from Gold to Silver)

Tags: loyalty-programs, air-new-zealand

I am an Air New Zealand Airpoints member, and I gained Silver status in mid January 2016, and Gold status in late November 2016.

I have gained sufficient status points (by flights (>= 203)) since earning Gold, and will have earned the remaining (<= 202) points via credit card *after* January 2017 but *before* November 2017 to *retain* Silver (405 points).

My question is this: Assuming I don't earn any more points from flights, **will I end up retaining Silver?**  (Retaining Gold is out of the question, and I don't have sufficient points (from flights) to earn Silver again outright (450 points, >= 225 from flights).

Comment: @pnuts it's both!  After November, loss of Gold **will** occur, but by then, I'll already have 405 (or more, but not 450) qualifying status points (ie, if I were Silver (instead of Gold), with a November renewal, I'd have retained Silver).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Airpoints](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/3799394-post4.html) practices what FlyerTalkers refer to as a *soft landing* in that failing to requalify for a status tier only drops you to a tier below, rather than losing all status (a *hard landing*).

Your Gold status is valid for 12 months from the time you earned it, which is to say November 2017. Even if you did not earn a single status point after attaining Gold, after your anniversary you would drop down to Silver status.

Your anniversary dates are maintained, however, so to retain Silver, you will be starting from zero as of November 2017, with 12 months to earn 405 status points to [retain Silver](https://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/status-points).